# How to display top 10 contributors in Confluence

Tags: statistics, confluence

I would like to display top 10 contributors to a space in Confluence in the last year that have created, updated or removed pages.

There is some statistics on `Browse Space > Activity`, but only monthly, not yearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{topusers:spaces=space_name|events=create,update,remove|timespan=365d}
```

- source: http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CONFEXT/Confluence+Usage+Tracking+Plugin
- example: http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/Top+Wiki+Contributors (click `Edit` to see the code)

Comment: and what if I want to get top5 users only ?

Answer (score -1):

I have just finished some macro work

http://zhapu-road.appspot.com/2010/08/2/confluence-top-contributors-profile-picture-and-personal-contributors-ranking-in-Confluence.html

Comment: link leads to 404 Error: Sorry, we were not able to find the requested page. We have logged this error and will look into it.